# AWS instance related issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an t2.small instance over AWS from last 3 months. Once in every week instance get down and I resolve it with instance stop and start. Can anyone suggest me the final solution for this?

Comment: Just imaging bringing your car to your car repair shop with _this_ detail-level of error description.

Comment: See also: "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: BTW: What is an "AWS instance"? Most likely, you are talking about EC2 or Lightsail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your description is not that detailed, this sounds like a memory issue. I would go over this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html
that sends monitoring metrics to cloudwatch, then see if there is any spike in memory before the instance crashes. Solution may vary to check what is causing the spike, or increase the instance size to get more memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into automation of instance reboot on Health Check failure described at this [CloudWatch User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html#AddingRebootActions). Though as suggested by @Uwe Keim, this is addressing symptoms, not all the potential root causes that can lead to instance becoming unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the CloudWatch agent to monitor custom metrics to check the health of a specific component running on your EC2 instance then use CloudWatch events to reboot the EC2 if it is not healthy.